# Are there rfid readers compatible with chrome hid api?

Tags: api, google-chrome, hid, rfid

I have tried using an rfid reader with chrome hid api,
         the device is detected in the chrome log (chrome://device-log)

```
HID User [15:49:22] HID device detected: vendorId=1133, productId=50475, name='Logitech USB Receiver', serial='', deviceId='/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/hidraw/hidraw0' 
HID User [15:49:22] HID device detected: vendorId=1133, productId=16398, name='Logitech K400', serial='', deviceId='/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:400E.0004/hidraw/hidraw1'
HID User [15:49:22] HID device detected: vendorId=5050, productId=24, name='Barcode Reader ', serial='', deviceId='/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.1/3-1.1:1.0/0003:13BA:0018.0006/hidraw/hidraw2'
```

but a call to

```
chrome.hid.getDevices({}, function (devices) {

    if (!devices || !devices.length) {
      console.log("No compatible device found.");
      return;
    }
```

ends up with "No compatible device found."

I have no problems connecting to the usb keyboard so I suspect that a different rfid could work just fine.

QUESTION:
Did anyone succeed using an rfid with chtome api? which rfid reader did you use? I'm interested in (possibly) low cost 125khz readers

Comment: Hi! Did you found answer? I have the same question and problem :)